# Beis HaMikdosh and Shechinah

Tags: beis-hamikdash, churban-destruction, maseches-gitin

I heard some mention the *Gemara* in *Gittin* which says that Titus y"m went into the קודש הקדשים with a harlot. He slashed the curtains, opened a *sefer torah* and had relations with the harlot. The Jews knew that if the *kohein gadol* messed up on the *avodah* in the קודש הקדשים he died on the spot, yet Titus did not die, but emerged from the קודש הקדשים unscathed. The reason Titus did not die on the spot was because there was no *kedushah* (i.e. the *Shechinah* departed) from the *Beis HaMikdosh*. Once there is no *Shechinah* remaining in the *Beis HaMikdosh* it just a bunch of bricks.

1. Where in the *Torah* does it says that if the *Kohein Gadol* messed up on the *avodah* in the קודש הקדשים, he died on the spot?
2. Is there any commentator that talks about the *Shechinah* departing from the *Beis HaMikdosh*?

Answer (score 2):

To your question about Kohein Gadol messing up on the avodah and dying on the spot, there is a gemoro in [Yoma 9a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=9&format=text)

> “The Second Temple stood for 420 years, ve-shimshu bo yoter mi-shelosh
>   meot Kohanim, and more than 300 served as High Priest over that
>   period.  Take out forty years in which Shimon the Tzaddik was the High
>   Priest and deduct another 80 years in which Yochanan the Kohen Gadol
>   served, and ten more years that Elazar b. Charson served.”  That
>   leaves 300 priests over 290 years.  “Kol echad ve-echad lo hotzi
>   shenato, none of them lived out their year in office.”

Rabbi Shmuel Herzfeld says

> When he entered the Holy of Holies, he literally put his life on the
>   line.  If he made a mistake in the service, if he had a bad thought,
>   or if he was simply unworthy, he could instantly be struck dead from
>   heaven.

This, he explains, is why the [Mishna in Yoma 70a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=70&format=text) says

> ויום טוב היה עושה לאוהביו בשעה שיצא בשלום מן הקודש:  “The High Priest
>   would make a party for all his loved ones when he entered the
>   Sanctuary in peace and left in peace without injury.”

About the second question:

See [this article](http://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/parsha/the-three-weeks-2/2014/07/25/0/?print)

which says what I have learnt

> The Talmud teaches that the Beis HaMikdash was destroyed because of
>   baseless hatred. Bnei Yisrael did not properly fulfill the mitzvah to
>   “love your fellow as yourself.” Their strife and infighting caused
>   the Shechinah to depart from the Beis HaMikdash, and once that
>   happened, our enemies were successful.

The source is [Sanhedrin 96b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=96b&format=text)

> A divine voice came forth from Heaven saying to Nevuzaradan   "Thou
>   hast slain a dead people, thou hast burned a Temple already burned,
>   thou hast ground flour already ground.”

which means that the essence of the Beis HaMikdash was already destroyed when he destroyed it because the Shechinah had already departed.